# Find a sentence's confidence score/similarity to a word2vec model

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec

I created two different word2vec models for two different topics or categories.

Now, if I give a new sentence as an input, how can I calculate the confidence score of that sentence to both the models. I mean, how do I calculate the percentage similarity or closeness of the sentences with both the models ?

Is it possible to get a pooled vector for one model so that I can compare it to a new sentence's vector.

Example -

Say I created two word2vec models for SPORTS and ACADEMICS. I created both the models using various sentences, pre-processing etc.

Now, say I give a sentence which is a mix of both SPORTS and ACADEMICS.

How do I know how much my sentence is in the SPORTS context and how much in the ACADEMICS using the already present model and the vector of this new sentence ?

Like, can I say that my new sentence has 70% similarity to SPORTS model and 50% similarity to academics model ?

Comment: Close _to what_? A word2vec model is a vectorial model where each token has a different position in vector space. So what exactly would you compare your sentence to? It doesn't really make sense as you put it now.

Comment: Unless you mean: get a pooled (averaged) vector representation for both models, and then calculate the distance between those representations? Please update your post to give more details, now it lacks clarity.

Comment: Edited the question with an example.